# FFmpeg pipe related issues

Tags: java, ffmpeg, pipe

I am new to FFmpeg and have very little knowledge of different codecs.

I am using pipes to provide input and to send out output from FFmpeg

The command I use is essentially

```
ffmpeg -i pipe:0  -f flv pipe:1
```

I am using a Java program that basically provides an input stream as standard input (pipe:0), FFmpeg converts the video into the required format and sends out to standard output(pipe:1) from where I stream out to my remote location.

My java program revolves around this piece of code, providing input and sending output as an output stream.

Essentially my program does what it is supposed to, however I see that the final output video file is not of the complete duration. It is like 10 sec duration, and my sample video is 21 mins! Also it is missing audio.

Do I need to provide more info to FFmpeg?

EDIT: When I replace the pipe with an input file and an output file,the output is generated correctly without any issues, when I use pipes the size of the file is still larger compared to original. Just in case if it helps to diagnose.

FFmpeg version SVN-r23418, Copyright (c) 2000-2010 the FFmpeg developers

  built on Jun  2 2010 04:12:01 with gcc 4.4.2

  configuration: --target-os=mingw32 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-avisynth --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-bzlib --enable-libgsm --enable-libfaad --enable-pthreads --enable-libvorbis --enable-libtheora --enable-libspeex --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libxvid --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libx264 --extra-libs='-lx264 -lpthread' --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-librtmp --extra-libs='-lrtmp -lssl -lcrypto -lws2_32 -lgdi32 -lwinmm -lcrypt32 -lz' --arch=x86 --cross-prefix=i686-mingw32- --cc='ccache i686-mingw32-gcc' --enable-memalign-hack

  libavutil     50.16. 0 / 50.16. 0

  libavcodec    52.72. 1 / 52.72. 1

  libavformat   52.67. 0 / 52.67. 0

  libavdevice   52. 2. 0 / 52. 2. 0

  libavfilter    1.20. 0 /  1.20. 0

  libswscale     0.11. 0 /  0.11. 0

Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'pipe:0':

  Metadata:

    major_brand     : isom

    minor_version   : 1

    compatible_brands: isom

    title           : 

    artist          : 

    date            : 

    album           : 

    comment         : 

Feedback: 

    genre           : 

  Duration: 00:21:46.63, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A

    Stream #0.0(und): Video: h264, yuv420p, 512x288 [PAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 403 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 50 tbc

    Stream #0.1(und): Audio: aac, 44100 Hz, mono, s16, 47 kb/s

Output #0, flv, to 'pipe:1':

  Metadata:

    encoder         : Lavf52.67.0

    Stream #0.0(und): Video: flv, yuv420p, 512x288 [PAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 1k tbn, 25 tbc

    Stream #0.1(und): Audio: libmp3lame, 44100 Hz, mono, s16, 64 kb/s

Stream mapping:

  Stream #0.0 -> #0.0

  Stream #0.1 -> #0.1

Comment: What formats and codecs are you going from, and going to?  What is the output of STDERR from FFmpeg?  Not all formats can be piped... some require seeking.

Comment: I need to convert a wide range of codecs, however currently I am testing with an h264 mp4 video to  flv format. In fact even if I provide -vcodec copy -acodec copy, it still does not output the full lengthty video

Comment: And, the output from STDERR?

Comment: It's worth noting that .flv is the container not the codec. I would recommend using `-vcodec libx264`

Comment: Brad, Adding stderr output to the question itself

Comment: Alastair, when I add -vcodec libx264 I get the following error "Error while opening encoder for output stream #0.0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height"

Comment: Adding to the information above, I dont see any audio loss when I simply do ffmpeg -i pipe:0  -f flv pipe:1, but the video is only 10 seconds long, though I see that the output file is fairly large and it did convert the whole video to flv from the console output. Also the video is not seekable.

Comment: What about stderr after the job has finished?

Comment: After the job finishes I see this line "video:21257kB audio:3517kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.977621%" This is for a video where a .mp4 is getting converted to .avi with -f avi option.

Comment: Ignoring the ambiguous codec options (you really ought to define them), it sounds like you're not passing passing the whole input file on the stdin. Perhaps you would like to share the code where you invoke ffmpeg?

Comment: What is the code you are using to read from stdout. It sounds like the buffer is getting filled when you pipe in the input and stops to let stdout be read. You need to be reading from standard output(pipe:1) async.